# I am unable to install and setup cordova on windows

Tags: cordova

I have installed cordova using: `- npm install -g cordova`
on the path `C:\windows\system32`. But I am unable to access the cordova.
When i run the command `cordova --version` it says `'cordova' is not recognized as an internal command.`
Kindly help.

Comment: Follow these directions: [Installing Cordova on Windows](https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html).  It appears that you need to install other products before you can install Cordova.

Comment: @Apurva suggest you to follow the official link for complete installation process - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Comment: I followed the same .But the problem still exists.

Comment: In this when I try to add platform ,I need to enter the folder by doing cd hello. But it shows cordova can't be recognized as enternal command

Comment: I have figured out the problem. I changed the directory where cordova get installed by default. so i was unable to access it globally.